# on click increase height and width of div also get content inside it using ajax

Tags: javascript

I am using on click event to increase height and width of div but in my case works fine for some divs but not for all divs. Some divs increasing height and width but not in all case. One more thing is like on click also I am getting content from DB using ajax.

Below is the code i am using:

```js
function addHighlightNote() {
  var selOffsets = checkHighlight(document.getElementById("detail_page"));
  var content_id = selOffsets.start + "," + selOffsets.end;

  var div = document.createElement("div");
  var sel = document.getSelection();

  div.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:yellow;height:1.5rem;width:1.5rem; position:relative; left:10%; float:right;border:1px solid #f3a73b;');
  div.setAttribute('id', "" + selOffsets.start + selOffsets.end);

  div.setAttribute('class', 'newDiv');

  div.setAttribute('title', 'Your Note');
  div.setAttribute('onclick', 'changeHeightWidthDiv("' + selOffsets.start + selOffsets.end + '")');

  div.setAttribute('onmouseleave', 'saveData("' + selOffsets.start + ',' + selOffsets.end + '" , "' + selOffsets.start + selOffsets.end + '") ');


  if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    range.collapse(false);
    range.insertNode(div);
  }
}


function changeHeightWidthDiv(id) {
  // alert(id);
  $('#' + id).css('height', '140px');
  $('#' + id).css('width', '200px');

  $('#' + id).css('font-size', '13px');
  $('#' + id).css('color', '#000');

  $('#' + id).attr('contentEditable', 'true');
  $('#' + id).css('overflow-y', 'scroll');

  $('#' + id).removeAttr("onclick");

  var token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/get-div-content',
    data: {
      _token: token,
      id: id
    },
    success: function(data) {

      $('#' + data['divid']).html(data['content']);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="addHighlightNote();"></button>
```

```
function checkHighlight(element)
{
   var start = 0;
      var end = 0;
      var doc = element.ownerDocument || element.document;
      var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
      var sel;
      if (typeof win.getSelection != "undefined") 
      {
          sel = win.getSelection();
          if (sel.rangeCount > 0) 
          {
                var range = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);

                var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
                preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);

                preCaretRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
                start = preCaretRange.toString().length;

                preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
                end = preCaretRange.toString().length;
          }
      } 
      else if ((sel = doc.selection) && sel.type != "Control")
       {
                var textRange = sel.createRange();
                var preCaretTextRange = doc.body.createTextRange();

                preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
                preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", textRange);

                start = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
                preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);

                end = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
      }
                return {start: start, end: end};
}
```

I know it small mistake but not able to get it. Please help.Also there is div which has id and have content in it. Content is dynamic so cannot post here. Hope now it will help you.

Comment: its like on click i am creating a div on left side of web page. And onclick on div increasing its height and weight. But on some div its working but not on all divs.

Comment: this much code i have.please help

Comment: If this is all the code you have, then you will not have a working (web application) at all. These are just 2 javascript functions that are never executed.To reproduce this issue you would need to supply at least the html as well, possible some css. Also don't just post all code, post the code that is needed to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Edited my question. Please check

Comment: I am getting start and end positions of selected word and creating div after it and using css getting it into right.

Comment: once div created using first function then onclick increases its height and width. which is only working for some divs not for all

Comment: `document.getElementById("detail_page")` will be undefined since you don't have an element with that id. Also you call the function `checkHighlight()` wich does not excist.